# Why doesn't Apollo query return updated value from cache after store reset?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client, react-state-management

I recently added [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/) local state to my react/next.js website. I'm using Apollo `client.writeData` function to update the cache and `useQuery` to pull the updates. Everything works but if I run Apollo's `client.resetStore()` and then perform actions which update the cache, components which use `useQuery` to get the updated values no longer get the values/update. So my changes to local state stop having any effect after `client.resetStore()`. I checked that the cache itself does update via Apollo developer tools. So `useQuery` is not rerun somehow when values update. Not sure what I'm missing.

This is the Apollo client setup:

```
import withApollo from 'next-with-apollo';
import ApolloClient, { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-boost';
import { IntrospectionFragmentMatcher } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import introspectionQueryResultData from '../../fragmentTypes.json';
import { gqlTypes } from 'helpers';

const fragmentMatcher = new IntrospectionFragmentMatcher({
  introspectionQueryResultData
});

function createClient({ ctx, headers, initialState }) {
  const cache = new InMemoryCache({ fragmentMatcher });
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    credentials: 'include',
    uri: 'graphql_url',
    cache: cache.restore(initialState || {}),
    headers: {
      cookie: headers?.cookie
    },
    resolvers: {}
  });

  // initialize state
  const initialLocalState = {
    callToReview: {
      __typename: gqlTypes.CallToReviewData,
      overallRating: 0,
      openUserReviewForm: false
    }
  };

  cache.writeData({
    data: initialLocalState
  });

  client.onResetStore(() => cache.writeData({ data: initialLocalState }));
  return client;
}

export default withApollo(createClient, { getDataFromTree: 'ssr' });
```

This is my query:

```
query consumptionAndCallToReview {
  consumptionMethods {
    _id
    slug
  }
  callToReview @client(always: true) {
    overallRating
    openUserReviewForm
  }
}
```

This is my component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
const MyComponent = props => {
  const callToReviewData = useQuery(consumptionAndCallToReviewQuery);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (callToReviewData?.openUserReviewForm) {
      // do something...
    }
  }, [callToReviewData]);

  return (
    // ...jsx
  )
}
```

and finally this I reset store by:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useApolloClient } from 'react-apollo';
const ResetComponent = props => {
  const client = useApolloClient();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (//some conditions) {
      client.stop();
      client.resetStore()
    }
  }, [callToReviewData]);

  return (
    // ...jsx
  )
}
```